# Scatter plot with markers representing a label?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume  Return  Date    Week_Number Year    Day Weekday mean_return volatility  labels
754 46.90   46.90   45.60   46.50   46.50   1077800 0.76    2020-01-02  0   2020    2   Thursday    -59.95  191.98       red
755 45.64   46.16   45.30   45.59   45.59   860000  -1.96   2020-01-03  0   2020    3   Friday  -59.95  191.98           red
756 45.00   46.24   44.59   46.19   46.19   951500  1.32    2020-01-06  1   2020    6   Monday  157.50  73.82            green
```

I have this data frame with the last column 'labels' - this is a subset of a larger dataframe that has labels 'green' and 'red' for each row based on a certain criteria.

I want to try and plot this on a scatterplot where each marker is the color assigned to it in the 'label' column. So every marker will be either red or green.

Is there a way to do this using matplotlib?

```
graf_one_plt = graf_one.plot.scatter(x = 'mean_return', y = 'volatility', c= 'green', s=25)
```

This is all I have at the moment!

Thanks

Comment: Try `c='labels'` in `graf_one.plot.scatter(...)`

Comment: That's the one, thanks!